# force divs to fill space to the left of another

Tags: html, css

Please see this pen for code and a visual of what I am trying to do http://codepen.io/MarkRBM/pen/pFHAr

the css in question is on line 801 -> 855

I want the 3 divs in the bottom left of .locscta to fill the space to the left of the .locslist div and directly below the .locsleft div.  I would like to do this without floats if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use inline-boxes, you could try vertical-align and resize width of these three boxes :
http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/eAvou

```
.locscta.wrapper {
  width:  $threecol*1.16;
  vertical-align:top;

}
.locscta.wrapper > div  {
  display:block;
  width:100%
}
```

Woud it look like what you expect ?